# Trailing backslash required for Window Mobile 7 IE

Tags: windows-phone-7, iis, ie-mobile

We have an IIS web application in our pre-production environment that has a quirky behaviour in Win Mobile 7.

Our application is accessed using a default page, so our canonical url is like: http://www.ourdomain.com/location/ourapplication

All browsers, with the exception of Windows Mobile IE9, fixes this URL up with a trailing slash: http://www.ourdomain.com/location/ourapplication/

As a result the CSS and media files are loaded correctly (`"includes/css/mycss.css"`) on these browsers. We have tested PC, MAC, OSX, Android and WinPhone. Only WinPhone is incorrectly processing this, and only on the first load. Windows Phone IE does not add the trailing slash.

I've tried using `"/includes/..."`, `"~/includes/..."`, `"../includes/..."` and `"http://www.ourdomain.com/locationname/ourapplication/includes..."` without any success.

Anyone got any ideas on the cause and/or solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried ../includes/  This should make the link relative to the site root.

Comment: @benni_mac_b I did. Same problem :-(